# Converting a date to string representation

Tags: ruby, date

I have a date like this:

```
Date.today - 7
```

I tried to convert it into a string:

```
@last_week = strftime((Date.today - 7), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I get the error `` "undefined method `strftime'" ``. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`@last_week = (Date.today - 7).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @sawa Why not?  I think it answers the question exactly.

Comment: @KeithBennett Please read the question. I have done some edits, but have not changed the question.

Comment: @sawa I understand what you're saying now.  It shows a way to make it work, but does not answer the original question as to why the original implementation does *not* work.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, but don't do it.:

```
module Kernel
  def strftime(date, format)
    date.strftime(format)
  end
end
```

for the reason, see below comments~~~~~

Comment: I think this is a Very Bad Idea.  Critical components of the Ruby runtime should not be polluted with special purpose methods whose aims are easily achieved with the methods already defined on the classes for which they are meaningful.

Comment: True, your answer will make his approach work.  However, I don't think the OP would insist on using an approach that is a bad idea if educated about the correct way to do it.  When someone on SO asks "How can I make [insert my very wrong approach that will wreak havoc here] work?", I believe it is more important for the sake of that person and teammates to educate as to best practices, than to enable them to write bad code. Or, at minimum, add a disclaimer saying something like "I don't suggest doing this because..., but if you insist you can do it like this". Am I wrong?

Comment: i didn't say you are wrong, maybe i should add something like: This is what you want, but don't do it..

Comment: Not enough, IMO.  It's important to explain *why* not to do it, so that the OP understands and will incorporate that understanding into the future.

Comment: I see now that you referred to my comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `strftime()` as though it was a standalone function.  In Ruby, there is no such function.  The correct way to do this is to call the method [Date#strftime()](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).

Here's an example to format today's date as a string:

```
Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

Now that you know how to get a date and format the date to a printable string, you can address your specific code need, which is

```
@last_week = (Date.today - 7).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This will give you the date formatted string "2016-04-28" (or thereabouts, depending on when you run the code).

Comment: Upvoted for actually attempting to educate the OP or anyone else that has the same issue AND not being pedantic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method as `strftime` on `Kernel` (although there is such instance method on `Date`), but you are trying to call such method.

**Addition by  @Keith Bennett**

You are not calling `strftime` with an explicit object to receive the method, so the Ruby runtime defaults to calling the method on `self`, which, in this context, is the top level object, an instance of `Object`, which inherits from `BasicObject` and includes the `Kernel` module.  None of these contain a `strftime` method.  However, the `Date` method *does* have `strftime` defined.  So you can do what you want to do by calling `strftime` on the calculated Date instance.

Comment: why is this answer downvoted? I dont know. As far as I know Sawa is correct.

Comment: I don't know, and I agree that it is correct.  Here is an elaboration of the point: You are not calling `strftime` with an explicit object to receive the method, so the Ruby runtime default to the top level object, which is an instance of `Object`, which inherits from `BasicObject` and includes the `Kernel` module.  None of these contain a `strftime` method.  However, the `Date` method *does* have `strftime` defined.  So you can do what you want to do by calling `strftime` on the calculated Date instance.